# Reusing Visual Studio installation download cache

Tags: visual-studio, installation, bootstrapper

I've downloaded visual studio 2022 recently and the installer gad saved the download cache.
I want to know is there any way to reuse the cache to install visual studio in
another computer?

I've searched official sites but solutions needed me to download installer
via bootstrapper not by using existing ones.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi, the download cache is actually a collection of installation packages and  it’s not supported to copy downloaded installation package to another computer and then install from the copied installation package. You can create an offline installation package instead.

Answer (score 1):

I‘m afraid that there’s no way to reuse the cache to install visual studio in another computer based on the current MS docs.

Firstly, you should know what does this cache folder do.

The Download cache is the folder path where you want to store the installation files and manifests.

It provides a source of installed packages that you need to repair/update/modify/uninstall the product.

In addition, compare to `Donwload all, then install` feature, it downloads vs packages that are similar to download cache packages because they are both installation package. This [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/create-an-offline-installation-of-visual-studio?view=vs-2022#use-the-download-all-then-install-feature) says:

> Do not try to transfer this downloaded installation package to another computer, as it's not designed to work that way.

**SO, it’s not supported to copy downloaded installation package to another computer and then install from the copied installation package.**

If you want to download an installation package and transfer it to or install it on another machine, then you'll need to create a layout by referring this [Create an offline installation package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/create-a-network-installation-of-visual-studio?view=vs-2022)

Steps:

(1)Download the Visual Studio bootstrapper to create the network layout

(2)Create the network layout

`vs_enterprise.exe --layout E:\VSLayout --lang en-US`

[image]

(3)Copy the layout to another machine or a network share

(4)Install Visual Studio from the local layout

`E:\VSLayout\vs_enterprise.exe --noWeb`

If you want to move package cache to another drive in the same machine ,you can use `Move the package cache`.

This [Move the package cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/configure-policies-for-enterprise-deployments?view=vs-2022) says:

> If you change the CachePath registry policy after any installations, you must move the existing package cache to the new location and make sure it's secured so that SYSTEM and Administrators have Full Control and that Everyone has Read access.

Answer (score 0):

Just maintain them in the same place that you keep ALL of your installation files that are required AFTER installation.  Name it something like:

\foo